# JayData Data model already created - add an OData action afterwards

Tags: t4, jaydata

I have an OData Web Api service where I create the controllers with a T4 template from the EF datamodel.
While doing that, I also create the Jaydata datamodel with T4.

But now, I have a partial class that will add an action to one of my controllers.

As the JayData file is also created by a T4 template, is there a way to add actions to one of the EntitySets later on?

Comment: Do you mean adding an action in the client at runtime?

Comment: @PeterAronZentai No. My Web Api Controllers are all created from T4 scripts, directly when I edit my data diagram (a tangible architect .tasl file). I also created a T4 script that will automatically create the Jaydata models. The Controllers are partial classes, and I now have the case where I add an additional action to one controller. I know how to do that for the controller (partial class), but I would also like to keep the autogeneration of the Jaydata models intact, and basically also would like to have this partial class stuff going on in the Jaydata model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I managed to do now is the following:
My generated JayData context looks like the following:

```
$data.EntityContext.extend('myNameSpace.MyContext', {
    'Cases': { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: myNameSpace.Case},
    // ... other Entitysets
}
```

Later, I extend this context like this:

```
myNameSpace.MyContext.extend('myNameSpace.MyExtendedContext', {
    'Cases': { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: myNameSpace.Case, actions: {
        'Checkout': { type: $data.ServiceAction, returnType: 'myNameSpace.Case', IsBindable: true, 'EntitySet': 'Cases', IsAlwaysBindable: true, params: [{ name: 'Id', type: 'Edm.Guid' }] }
    }
}
```

So I can use my action if I later use my extended context. I think this should be good enough.

My Typescript definitions for this look like this:

```
declare module myNamespace {
export class CaseExtensions extends $data.EntitySet<myNamespace.Case> {
    Checkout: {
        (Id: string, handler?: (result: myNamespace.Case) => void): $data.IPromise<Case>;
        (params?: { Id?: string; }, handler?: (result: myNamespace.Case) => void): $data.IPromise<Case>;
    };
}

export class MyExtendedContext extends MyContext {
    Cases: CaseExtensions;
}
}
```